# Is "a friend of his" a used phrase?

Tags: adjectives, possessives

I know that *a friend of mine* is a used phrase, but is the phrase also used with other personal possessive adjectives?

> I met a friend of his.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are some stats from the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://www.americancorpus.org/), the [British National Corpus](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/), and Google:

```
                      COCA    BNC    Google

a friend of mine      1227    230    33.90M
a friend of his        274     53    25.30M   
a friend of hers       130     20     7.63M
a friend of ours        82     13    13.10M
a friend of theirs      25      3     1.82M
```

Average number of incidences per million words in different contexts (COCA):

```
           SPOKEN FICTION MAGAZINE NEWSPAPER ACADEMIC

...mine     6.08    3.10    3.30      1.35      .52
...his       .95    1.06     .56       .48      .18
...hers      .32     .73     .3        .14      .05
...ours      .51     .23     .15       .05      .02
...theirs    .08     .12     .02       .04      .04
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I've heard that quite a few times in England and initially I was quite confused by it as well. Also note that in some cases there is a subtle difference between "a XXXXX of him" and "a XXXXX of his". For example, "a photo of him" is a photo on which he is to be seen, while "a photo of his" is a photo which he possesses (but not necessarily appears on it).

Comment: Is it also used in American English, or is it used only in British English?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: It's also perfectly good American English.

Comment: Yes, *"A friend of him" is something that I believe no native English speaker would say.

Comment: @Colin That's going a bit far, I've heard many english speakers say that. Perhaps incorrectly sometimes, but it would be perfectly good english to say (for example) *"he should make a friend of him, not an enemy."*

Comment: @ghoppe: Picky. Your example is "make [a friend] [of him]". It doesn't include the phrase "a friend of him".

Comment: Does it apply only to possessive pronouns, or does it apply to apostrophe s's as well? Should it be "It was Joe, a friend of Tom's" or "It was Joe, a friend of Tom"? How about living things other than humans? (e.g. "A branch of the tree" or "A branch of the tree's"?)