# "A friend of his" type expression for abstract entities

Tags: grammaticality, possessives

Like many non-native speakers, formulations like "a friend of his" strike me as counter-intuitive, but I'm trying to adapt. Now I have a strange situation: I want to apply it to abstract entities. The sentence would be:

> "What can we do with assignments and hierarchies of theirs?"

(I use assignments because I'm trying to avoid repetition. In the real text it's "blabla transmogrifying assignments").

I think this sounds awkward, and I can't recall ever having read anything like that. Is it possible that this type of construction is only valid for people? Or maybe it's a slightly different meaning of "of", and there's no possessive aspect to my usage of "of"?

I'm aware of [Why do you say "friend of mine" instead of "friend of me"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1535/why-do-you-say-friend-of-mine-instead-of-friend-of-me)
and 
[Is "a friend of his" a used phrase?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10048/is-a-friend-of-his-a-used-phrase) but all the examples had a person as the possessing subject.

Comment: There are definitely ways this can sound natural: "speaking of foo and bar functions, a property of theirs is baz"; "that wheel of its is always coming loose". Some constructions are less natural: ?"speaking of the table, a color of its is blue". May be related to how much agency we imagine the entity in question has, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I would have cast that sentence as "What can we do with assignments and their heirarchies?". I can't even imagine saying, "I sat on the table, and a leg of its was wobbly." I can't think of an inanimate example were that construction sounds natural.

Comment: "I sat on a table and one of its legs was wobbly."

Comment: Exactly, but you'd never say "... a leg of its ..."